# Disable commandButton in JSF

Tags: jsf, icefaces

This seems like it should be pretty straightforward but I'm not feeling it.

I have a JSF CommandButton that executes a long running serverside task (10-15 seconds).  I've seen forms where the button context changes after it's been clicked (The label on the button changes and the button becomes disabled until the processing is complete).

I'm using ICEFaces and have the disabled property set to a boolean on the underlying page code.

The action listener bound to the button changes that boolean to disable it but alas, no changes on the JSP.

Anyone?

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is to change the status of the button using Javascript:

```
<h:commandButton ... onclick="this.disabled=true"/>
```

---

**Edit regarding the comment:**

If the previous code does not submit the form, then you have to disable the button a little time after the click, not "during" the click itself. You can do that using the following code:

```
<h:commandButton ... onclick="setTimeout('this.disabled=true', 100);"/>
```

I'm not sure if the fact to use the *this* keyword directly in the setTimeout method will work correctly. If not, you can use another way to do that:

```
<h:commandButton ... onclick="disableButton(this.id);"/>
```

with the following Javascript function:

```
function disableButton(buttonId) {
    setTimeout("subDisableButton(" + buttonId + ")", 100);
}

function subDisableButton(buttonId) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(buttonId);
    if (obj) {
        obj.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

(I'm sure this code can be enhanced, thus)

Comment: sadly, with icefaces, this approach doesn't work.  It actually disables it from submitting at all.  I tried doing it onMouseUp but that disables it after the first click...

Comment: And what about my new response?

Comment: Can I enable the button back after disabled it?

Answer (score 1):

You should use an ice:commandButton instead of h:commandButton, since it has the partialSubmit property, which will perform the action as an AJAX call. This should refresh your button's state, so if the property on the server has been set to false, your button should be disabled.

Comment: +1 for taking advantage of the framework the OP is using to solve the problem in an elegant manner.

Answer (score 1):

do a javascript submit(); first and then disable the button

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the solution from romaintaz

For a Firefox specific solution, the following works (it does not work in IE):

`<h:commandButton ... onclick="disableButton(this.id);" />`

Using Javascript function:

```
function disableButton(buttonId) {

    var obj = document.getElementById(buttonId);

    if (obj) {
       setTimeout(function(thisObj) { thisObj.disabled=true; }, 50, obj);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do it after icefaces has updated the DOM. you can use `ice.onAfterUpdate(callback)`:

Here with jQuery

```
ice.onAfterUpdate(function(){
    updateButtons();
});

function updateButtons(){
   if(!isButtonEnabled()){
    jQuery(".myButton").attr('disabled', true);
    jQuery(".myButton").removeClass("iceCmdBtn").addClass("iceCmdBtn-dis");
   }else{
    jQuery(".myButton").removeAttr('disabled');
    jQuery(".myButton").removeClass("iceCmdBtn-dis").addClass("iceCmdBtn");
   }
}
```